# Multiple arrays in one loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm currently working on a Symfony 2.7 and I have in my controller 3 arrays. But I want to show all of this 3 arrays in one array in the view. Someone know

You can see the return in my controller here with my 3 arrays (entities, tabStatus and tabName) I can't merge the arrays in one.

```
return $this->render('testAdminBundle:Default:showBt.html.twig', 
array('entities' => $entities, 'tabStatus' => $tabStatus, 'tabName' => $tabName));
```

And here my view :

```
   <div class="bs-example">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Login</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Items</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for value in entities %}
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ value.login }}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ value.items }} / 2400</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div><!-- /example -->
      <br>
```

You can see in my view i show only the array entites because I can't put the 2 others arrays in the for. It is event possible to do something like this :
**{% for value1 in entities, value2 in tabStatus, value3 in tabName %}** ? Or maybe I need to use key in twig ?

Thanks per advance !

PokeRwOw

Comment: Maybe you should rebuild 3 arrays `$entities, $tabStatus, $tabName` to one array?

Comment: the arrays have the same key? The same length? So you want to avoid to make three different loop with the same html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{% for key, value in entities %}
    {{ value }} {{ tabStatus[key] }} {{ tabName[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you can't merge them into one? did you try `array_merge_recursive` instead of `array_merge`? else Alexander Micklewright solution should be what you want. or the use of multiple foreach and use `includes` to avoid duplicated codes.